# Proof using definition of binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let n be n$_1$ + n$_2$ + n$_3$ + ... + n$_t$ where each n$_i$ is a positive integer. Use the definition of the binomial coefficient to prove that:

$\binom{n_1 + ... + n_t}{n_1}$$\binom{n_2 + ... + n_t}{n_2}$$\binom{n_3 + ... + n_t}{n_3}$ ...$\binom{n_t}{n_t}$ = $\frac{n!}{n_1!n_2!...n_t!}$

I know that the definition of $\binom{n}{k}$ is $\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. I will be fine once it is all in factorial form. I'm just confused about how to convert the left hand side into factorials because of what n is defined as.

Answer (score 1):

$n=n_1+n_2+...+n_t$

so simply applying the definition you stated you get

$\frac{n!}{n_1!(n_2!+...+n_t!)}\frac{(n_2!+...+n_t!)}{n_2!(n_3!+...+n_t!)}\frac{(n_3!+...+n_t!)}{n_3!(n_4!+...+n_t!)}...$

and so on...so you will immediately see that in the expression you have lot of crossing simplyfing quantities leading you to the solution

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*} \prod_{i = 1}^{t} \binom{n_i + \cdots + n_t}{n_i} &=  \prod_{i = 1}^{t} \frac{(n_i+\cdots + n_t)!}{n_i! (n_{i+1} + \cdots + n_t)!} \\ 
&= \prod_{i = 1}^{t} \frac{1}{n_i!} \prod_{i = 1}^{t} \frac{1}{ (n_{i+1} + \cdots + n_t)!} \prod_{i =1}^{t} (n_i+\cdots + n_t)! \\ 
& =  \prod_{i = 1}^{t} \frac{1}{n_i!} \prod_{i = 1}^{t} \frac{1}{ (n_{i+1} + \cdots + n_t)!} \prod_{i =0}^{t-1} (n_{i+1}+\cdots + n_t)! \\ 
& =\left( \prod_{i = 1}^{t}\frac{1}{n_i!}\right) n!
\end{align*}